# sed and regex rule to substitute text

Tags: regex, sed

I have the following text:

> Before doing anything, curses must be initialized.  This is done by
> calling the :func:`~curses.initscr` function, which will determine the
> terminal type, send any required setup codes to the terminal, and
> create various internal data structures.  If successful,
> :func:`initscr` returns a window object representing the entire
> screen; this is usually called ``stdscr`` after the name of the
> corresponding C variable.

I want replace:

> :func:`~curses.**initscr**`

with:

> **`initscr** https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.initscr`_

and I tried the following sed rule:

```
's@ :func:`~curses\.\(.*\)`@ `\1 <https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.\1>`_ @g'
```

but the following is the result:

> Before doing anything, curses must be initialized.  This is done by
> calling the `initscr` function, which will determine the terminal
> type, send any required setup codes to the terminal, and create
> various internal data structures.  If successful, :func:`initscr`
> returns a window object representing the entire screen; this is
> usually called ``stdscr`
> <https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.initscr`
> function, which will determine the terminal type, send any required
> setup codes to the terminal, and create various internal data
> structures.  If successful, :func:`initscr` returns a window object
> representing the entire screen; this is usually called ``stdscr`>`_
> after the name of the corresponding C variable. ::

Comment: maybe: ```s@ :func:`~curses\.\([^`][^`]*\)`@ `\1 <https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.\1>`_ @g' ```

Comment: yeah thank you so much, it works. But could you explain me the part **\([^`][^`]*\)**

Comment: ```[^`][^`]*``` - anything BUT backtick repeated 1 or more times - similar to ```[^`]+```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
sed -E 's@ :func:`~curses\.([^`]+)`@ `\1 <https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.\1>`_ @g' file
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wGLDmo/1)

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   :func:`~curses          ' :func:`~curses'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^`]+                    any character except: '`' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  `                        '`'
```